# Show that $\langle x,y\rangle_A = \langle Ax,Ay\rangle$ is an inner product on $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix with real enteries. Define $\langle x,y\rangle_A = \langle Ax,Ay\rangle, \quad x,y \in \mathbb R^n$ , where $\langle,\rangle$ is a standard inner product on $\mathbb R^n$. Then  $\langle x,y\rangle_A$ is an inner product iff

1)  $\ker A = \{0\}$.

2) $\operatorname{rank} A= n$.

3) all eigenvalues of $A$ are positive.

4) all eigen value of $A$ are non negative.

Clearly if $\ker A \neq \{0\}$, then there exist $x \neq 0$ such that $Ax =0$, then $\langle Ax, Ax\rangle_A = 0$, then $\langle ,\rangle_A$ is not inner product, so $\ker A = \{0\}$, thus rank of $A$ is $n$.

I am unable to check the 3) and 4) option. Please help to check the other option. Thank you

Comment: Note that $\langle x,y\rangle$ is standard notation and $<x,y>$ is not. $\qquad$

Comment: Thanks for editting, further, i will keep in  mind .

Comment: I noticed later that $\ker A=\{0\}$ is equivalent to $\rm{rank} A=n.$ [for an $n \times n$ matrix, viewed as a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to itself] So conditions (1) and (2) are really the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\lambda=0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then there is a nonzero $v$ for which $Av=\lambda v=0,$ and you have already noted that in this case $\langle Av,Av \rangle=0.$ So that only leaves possibility 3. There would still be needed a proof that *if* all eigenvalues positive then one gets an inner product this way.

**Added:** You seem to have a logic error in treating option (1). That says, that *iff* kernel of $A$ is zero, then one gets an inner product. But what you did was to assume kernel nonzero, then get that one doesn't get an inner product. This is one direction of the iff statement (1), rather than a refutation of choice (1). So it may be that choice (1) is the correct one after all.

As for choice (3), it does not work since if $A=-I$ all eigenvalues of $A$ are $-1,$ yet one does get an inner product by the construction.

So my suggestion is to try to show the other direction for choice (1), i.e. that *if* kernel of $A$ is zero then one does get an inner product by the construction.

Comment: Is there any pssibilty if any eigen value of $A$ is negative , then $\langle , \rangle_A$ is innner product

Comment: Please do not mind , i want to more explanation about  3) option.

Comment: @user120386 I have been looking at that. What I was pointing out is one can rule out 3 of the 4 choices, so if this is just a multiple choice question it has to be the case (3) choice. When I looked at a negative eigenvalue it led nowhere as $\lambda$ comes out *twice* so one gets $\lambda^2$ in front of the $\langle Av,Av \rangle$ which is not a contradiction, Will look more, but likely someone here could answer this immediately.

Comment: @user120386 I just put in some more to answer, it seems choice (3) is not right by the example of $A=-I.$ So choice (1) must be the right one, and as I noted your argument did not get rid of that choice, instead it showed one of the directions of the iff in choice (1).

Comment: @user120386 Finishing the iff on choice 1 is not hard, the bilinearity of the new inner product is immediate from that of the old, and the fact that $Ax$ is a linear map. The positive definite part: From $\langle Ax,Ax \rangle =0$ and property of old inner product comes $Ax=0,$ and then from kernel of $A$ being zero we get $x=0$ as desired.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41424/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-user120386).

Answer (score 1):

@user120386 Since we know that $Ker A =\{ 0 \}$ and $Rank$ $A = n $, for $option$ $3$ consider the forward direction that a matrix $A$ such that $\langle x,y\rangle_A$ is an inner product defined by $\langle x,y\rangle_A = \langle Ax,Ay\rangle, \quad x,y \in \mathbb R^n$ , lets consider a matrix $A$ of order $2$ as  $A =\begin{bmatrix}1&-2\\-2&1\end{bmatrix}$ , then $A$ still defines inner product as $Ker A = \{ 0 \}$ but the eigenvalues of $A$ are $-1$ and  $3$ , violating the 3rd option that all eigenvalues are positive and since the if condition is violated there is no iff statement left . thus 3rd option is incorrect .

```
 Please comment if the above answer seem incorrect.
```